# Best way to store data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, storage

Evening,

I've no training in Databases, and I'm a bit lost.

Essentially I've this data:

```
Game
    name_of_game varchar(?);
    screen_shots ?
         screen_shot_1
         screen_shot_2
              ...
         screen_shot_n
/Game
```

What is the best way to store the screen_shot_n data?

Do I try to use a serialized array?  Or do I need to try to make another table and store it there?  BTW, there are 30k 'Game'

I'm using PHP and MySQL if that'd help in anyway...

Comment: `screen_shot_n` is what? no of screen shots?

Comment: You need to read up on `Primary Keys`, `Foreign Keys` and `Master-Detail` relationships.

Comment: also, do you care to know which user made the screen shot?  that will add a little complexity

Comment: I should have cleared that each screenshot is just a URL.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use a separate screen shots table.

*Game Table*

```
game_id integer
name varchar
```

*Screenshots Table*

```
screenshot_id integer
game_id integer
screenshot varchar <--- a file name (or a blob or however you are storing the screenshot)
```

And then you can find the game's screenshots with:

```
SELECT * FROM screenshots WHERE game_id="123";
```

Comment: I think this is the best proposal to my query. 

Is there a 'limit' on the number of tables a given database should have?  

Because, this was a small example, I have other fields within 'Game' that require the same attention 'screenshot' does.

Comment: If you run into a table limit in mysql, you either need to change your further optimize schema or use a different database.

Answer (score 1):

Storing images in MySQL is not a good idea. I would suggest that you keep a master table for game name and game ID, then store game ID and timestamp (with an optional random key) in another table. Store the screenshots in a folder in the format timestamp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a bin type fields, and store the data there,

Although being its binary data, maybe just use local storage and just link to it from the DB?

YOu can .htaccess it to protect the directory and stream the content with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in seperate tables.  Something like this:

Table 1: GameInfo         Fields: gameid int, nameofgame varchar(X)

Table 2: GameScreenShots  Fields: ID int, gameid int, screenshotimage ??(X)

You'll want to have ID's on the table so you can reference the screen shots from the game table.  I would recommend them to be integer as using the name of the game for id's can be tricky.  Depending on if your storing an actual image of the screenshot or a link to the image will determine the type of your screenshotimage field.